# How do I create a hyperlink on a Razor page to an image stored in wwwroot?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I create a hyperlink to an image stored in wwwroot on a Razor page?

Example:

```
@{
  var WFR = "~/images/Certifications/" + (@Model.WFR ??  "../LogoSmall.jpg");
  <img src="@WFR" asp-append-version="true" />  // Works great!
  <a asp-action="@WFR">see document</a>    // Fails miserably
}
```

The img tag renders the image just fine.  But the anchor tag prepends a controller/action which routes me to my error page.  This is what the tag helper generates:
https://localhost:44394/Employment/~/images/Certifications/12144abb-6af2-424f-b005-4c2039228934_WFR2016.jpg.  Setting asp-controller="" just brings me to the home controller.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd be setting an action.  You don't want the link to go to an action

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any tag helpers for this, just set the tag to link to your image -

```
<a href="@WFR" target="_blank">see document</a>
```

Comment: I thought so too, but doing it this way also prepends the controller and action: https://localhost:44394/Employment/Details/~/images/Certifications/12144abb-6af2-424f-b005-4c2039228934_WFR2016.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

A user in another forum suggest this: Url.Content()

```
  <a href="@Url.Content(@WFR)">see document</a>
```

... and it works!!